# Generate geometry hash in application, or let postgis do it?

Tags: postgresql, go, postgis

I'm using Go to track delivery locations, and I'm wondering whether I should generate the geometry hash string in Go, or let postgres do it via `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($1, $2), 4326)` in my query.

I have not worked with geometries before so I am not sure which is better, and my application clients send the server a [lon,lat] which I can use.

Comment: Can you explain what a "geometry hash string" is?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_hashing

Comment: @user1354934 if this use case of yours only create a point in a certain SRS, it actually irrelevant whether you do it in Go or PostgreSQL. However, I would argue that it might save some effort letting PostGIS do the job, and it would make your application portable - in case you have other clients in the future. Good luck!